# How to delete footer in Postleaf

Tags: php, content-management-system

I just recently installed the [Postleaf](https://www.postleaf.org/) blogging platform and all I wanted to do is edit the theme that I am using in this platform, so I opened the footer file in this theme and it looked like this:

```
    </div>
    <footer class="animated fadeIn" id="footer">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <form class="search-form" action="{{search_url}}" method="GET">
                <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search">
                <button type="submit">Go</button>
            </form>
            <p class="copyright"><span>Made by {{@settings.title}}.</span> <span>Powered by Postleaf.</span></p>
            <a href="https://github.com/postleaf/phantom" class="theme">Theme: Phantom</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    {{postleaf_foot}}

    {{! Deferred scripts }}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="{{theme_url 'assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'}}"></'+'script>');
    }
    </script>

    <script src="{{theme_url 'assets/js/stellar.js'}}"></script>
    <script src="{{theme_url 'assets/js/phantom.js'}}"></script>
    <script src="{{theme_url 'assets/js/jquery.timeago.min.js'}}"></script>

    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("time.timeago").timeago(); });</script>

</body>
```

I deleted the footer and kept only the below portion:

```
    </div>
    {{! Deferred scripts }}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="{{theme_url 'assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'}}"></'+'script>');
    }
    </script>

    <script src="{{theme_url 'assets/js/stellar.js'}}"></script>
    <script src="{{theme_url 'assets/js/phantom.js'}}"></script>
    <script src="{{theme_url 'assets/js/jquery.timeago.min.js'}}"></script>
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("time.timeago").timeago(); });</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I refresh the preview in my admin panel I see no difference, in fact I see the same footer. So how exactly do I delete the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cory here (creator of Postleaf).

In Postleaf, handlebar templates are cached for optimal performance. You'll need to go to *Settings > Advanced* in the admin panel to clear it. (Scroll down to find the button.)

There's also a checkbox that you can toggle to disable caching during development, but I highly recommend turning it back on in production. Your server will thank you.

Also, feel free to post to the [community forum](https://community.postleaf.org) where you're more likely to get quicker feedback :)